# How to find if the keyboard is covering a control

Tags: livecode

I have a code that moves a group of control when the keyboard is activated. But I only want it to run when the keyboard is covering the control that activated the keyboard. I am using the code below but it is not correctly determining when the control is hidden by the keyboard.

Stack Script

```
lStackSize,lStackHeight
global gBottom

on openstack

   set the fullscreenmode of me to "exactFit" 
   put the loc of group "controls" into lStackLoc
   put the effective working screenRect into lStackSize
   put item 4 of lStackSize - item 2 of lStackSize  into lStackHeight

end openstack

-------------------------------

on keyboardactivated

   answer "control bottom" && gbottom

   put the effective working screenRect into tStackSize
   set itemdel to comma
   put item 4 of tStackSize - item 2 of tStackSize  into tStackHeight

    answer "tStackHeight" && tStackHeight & return & "gbottom" && gBottom

    if gbottom<tStackHeight then

       answer "control Visible"

    else 

        answer"control Hidden"
        put gbottom - tStackHeight into tYMove
        put item 2 of lStackLoc - tYMove into tNewLocY
        put item 1 of lStackLoc & "," & tNewLocY into tStackLoc
        move group "controls"  to tStackLoc 

    end if


end keyboardactivated

---------------------------

on keyboardDeactivated

   move group "controls"  to lStackLoc

end keyboardDeactivated
```

control script

```
global gBottom

on openfield

  put  the bottom of me into gBottom

end openfield
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effective screenRect refers to the rectangle that is actually available on screen (visible the part of the screen that is really used by the app). The working screenRect is the part of the screen that isn't used by e.g. the status bar.

```
put the effective working screenRect into myRect
if the topleft of control x is not within myRect \
 or the bottomright of control x is not within myRect then
   // control x is outside the visible part of the window
end if
```

`The working screenRect` might be sufficient, but the docs specifically refer to the keyboard when discussing `effective`

Comment: Mark, using your response I have written this code: `   put the effective working screenRect into myRect
   
   answer "Control" && gActiveControl \
         & return & "myRect" && myRect \
         & return & "topleft" && the topleft of control gActiveControl \
         & return & "bottomright" &&  the bottomright of control gActiveControl
   
   if the topleft of control gActiveControl is not within myRect or the bottomright of control gActiveControl is not within myRect then
      
      answer "control Visible"
      
   else 
      
      answer"control Hidden"
              
   end if `

Comment: I have tow controls one remains completely visible when the keyboard is activated and the other is completely hidden but the code determine that both are hidden. The first message for the control that bemains completely visible is: Control "comboboxmenu" myRect 0,25,720,1024, topleft 82,70 Bottomright 184,92

Comment: It was not working in the simulator but tried it on a mobile phone and I get different response for the two controls. Only problem is that it returns the hidden control as visible and the visible one as hidden.

Comment: Guess I can fix that by using `within` instead of `not within` in the IF statement

Comment: Probably, but I've read my own code many times now and I don't see the problem. That's a little frustrating. I'll try again later.

Comment: It's does work when I remove the not. Actually you code it right. Not with is the same as not visible or hidden. Sorry for my absent mindedness.